# Is GridFS faster than usual FS?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I wonder whether storing all the uploaded files in GridFS is faster than storing them on the usual filesystem, e.g. Ext4 (in terms of reading/writing speed and average server load).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general it's [slower](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2010/02/17/serving-files-out-of-gridfs/) for usual filesystem access style. But it can benefit from nice MongoDB features:

- You can associate any metadata with the files and query it in a usual manner. Actually files are stored as regular Mongo documents in `fs.files` and `fs.chunks` collections.
- Replication. With a replica set you will get an (almost) instant backup, failover and read scalability (read request can go to slave nodes).
- Sharding. Like any other collection it's possible to distribute files across multiple Mongo instances with auto-sharding. This will improve write scalability.

Answer (score 2):

[When to use GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-when-to-use-gridfs)

> - If your filesystem limits the number of files in a directory, you can use GridFS to store as many files as needed.
> - When you want to keep your files and metadata automatically synced and deployed across a number of systems and facilities. When using
>     geographically distributed replica sets MongoDB can distribute files
>     and their metadata automatically to a number of mongod instances and
>     facilitates.
> - When you want to access information from portions of large files without having to load whole files into memory, you can use GridFS to
>     recall sections of files without reading the entire file into memory.